Manga where the mc got possessed by someone
The story begins with the main character getting possessed by someone. The one who possessed her knew that this world was in a story she read (I don't know if this is a novel or a game story she read). One day, the person who possessed the MC found a problem and so he was hated by everyone and then he was depressed until the MC got her body back and decided to take revenge on the person who made the person who possessed her suffer. (If I'm not mistaken The MC is the villainess in the story that the person who possessed the MC read)

I'm afraid that that's the plotline for several manga and manhwa.

This is different, the mc wasn't the one who possesses but the one who got possessed and still can see what the person who possessed her do

I'm having a bit of trouble parsing that first sentence... so the story begins with the mc being possessed? Or is it that the MC is possessing a character? Is this set in a fantasy world? The modern world?

Yess! Thanks sir for helping me

As per this Reddit post, might this be Akuyaku Reijou no Naka no Hito: Danzai Sareta Tenseisha no Tame Usotsuki Heroine ni Fukushuu Itashimasu aka The One Within The Villainess?


A girl who had reincarnated as Remilia, the villainess of an otome game tries to clear her name. However, the real Remilia who had been watching all along inside awakens.
Now it's time for the true villainess' revenge to begin!

Found with a search for manga main character villainess possessed
